# Forwarding Traffic To Particular IP using IPTABLES

Tags: linux, networking, ip, iptables, nat

I am dealing with 3 machines (VMs) :-

A :-172.20.10.1 (Client)

B :-172.20.10.2 (Original Server)

C:-172.20.10.5 (Redirect Server)

Now I want A to visit B and B to forward that to C.

I was able to achieve this by using :-

`iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.20.10.5:80
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE`

But now I want to do this for one IP only (I.E) 172.20.10.1 to 172.20.10.5 when it tries to access 172.20.10.2 .. I have already tried [The answer here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/156151/iptables-routing-incoming-ip-to-another-destination-ip-question?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa).

and Yes `net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1` is also set.

Comment: This cannot work unless B is C’s next hop to A. Otherwise, C will directly send its response to A, which is expected a response from B. As such, the response will be treated as unsolicited traffic and discarded. Since this is apparently about HTTP, are you willing to deploy a reverse proxy?

Answer (score 0):

add the following to prerouting

```
-s 172.20.10.1/32,172.20.10.2/31,172.20.10.4/31
```

Answer (score 0):

On the crossposted copy to unix.SE, I answered:

Simply add something to match the ip you want the rule to match:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -s 172.20.10.1 -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.20.10.5:80
```

and the OP left a comment simply saying "This doesn't work..", to which I must ask: How doesn't this work? Is no traffic forwarded or is traffic from other clients still forwarded or ...?

Comment: I commented on the question to clarify why this cannot work: C will directly send its response to A, which is expecting it from B. Port forwarding only works under very specific circumstances. Basically on networks connected to everything else through a NAT router and nothing but.

Comment: It gets rather complicated (and hard to see the point of), but adding a route to A via B on C, might solve it (I'm not planning on setting up three boxes just to test that).

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly this problem . Finally I figured it out.

1. client connecting to server JUMPER on port 2222
2. JUMPER server forwards all packet on port 2222 to dest_server_ip:dest_server_port
3. dest_server replies to JUMPER server
4. JUMPER server forwards all packet from dest_server to client

for this firs enable port forwarding by setting

```
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
```

in `/etc/sysctl.conf` file. Then use this commands :

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 2222 -j DNAT --to-destination dest_server_ip:dest_server_port
iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp -d dest_server_ip --dport dest_server_port -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A POSTROUTING -t nat -p tcp -d dest_server_ip --dport dest_server_port  -j MASQUERADE
```

finally for saving iptables rules

```
sudo /sbin/iptables-save > /etc/iptables/rules.v4
```